# Add binary numbers like decimal numbers in Java. eg 0101 + 0110 = 0211

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I needed to write a program which adds binary numbers as if they were decimal. But it isn't working like I expected.

```
int i = 0101, j=0001;
System.out.println(i+j);
```

I expected the answer to be either 6 (i.e decimal of sum of 0101 and 0001) or maybe 0102 (as I am adding them as simple decimal numbers). But unexpectedly, I am getting 66. Can anybody kindly explain this? Or may be help me with the code to add two binary numbers as decimal numbers.

Comment: How are 0211 or 0102 binary numbers?

Comment: No they aren't. I just want to add binary numbers as if they are simple decimal numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You're using octal literals, i.e. `0101` = `65` = `1 * 8² + 1`. To use binary literals use the following notation:

```
int i = 0b101, j = 0b1;
```

If you want to print a int as binary, use [`Integer.toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) to get the string representation of a `int` in binary.

Comment: but how to print it as Binary ?

Comment: @OSryx you can use `Integer.toBinaryString(int)` to display it in binary.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(i),2);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(j),2);
System.out.println(num1+num2);
```

First we need to convert the number from binary to decimal. And for that you need to parse it using the parse commands for the `Integer` wrapper class. Then you can add.

The format `Integer.parseInt(String,radix)` can be used to convert any string of digits to the base `radix`.

Comment: `i` and `j` are not Strings ??

Comment: No they are `int`s as per OP's code.